# getElementById won't work

Tags: javascript

I'm just starting to learn JavaScript and can't figure out why getElementById won't work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>The Rock</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    text-align: center;
}
-->
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

function touchRock() { 
    var username = prompt("What is your name?");

    if (username) { alert("Hello, "+username+"! I am The Rock.");
    document.getElementById("rockimg").scr = "rock2.png";}
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>



<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><img id="rockimg" src="rock1.png" align="middle" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="touchRock();"  /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The idea is that once the user click on the rock, asks for his name, greets him and changes the image. The name/greeting part works, but the image doesn't change.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You got a typo.
Change `.scr` into `.src` and it will work

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342/187073) by removing these typo-related questions - we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo on this line:

`document.getElementById("rockimg").scr`

Should be `src` not `scr`

Answer (score 1):

change

```
document.getElementById("rockimg").scr
```

to

```
document.getElementById("rockimg").src
```

(it's **src**, not scr)